# Почему не отображаться мой сайт в Google Knowledge Graph?

Tags: javascript, json, seo, schema.org, google-search

Почему мой [сайт](https://www.fashion-flash.de) не отображается справа при поиске по слову Fashion Flash?

Например, если прописать в поиск "цирк дю салей", то там есть граф справа с короткой информацией о них и ивенты. Целью у меня было тоже самое сделать и на своём. На сайте разместил, согласно рекомендациям, schema.org и гугл, даже в search console вручную провёл маркер ([скрин](http://prnt.sc/emzpa4) прилагаю). Даже в Google My Business компания зарегистрирована. Страница проиндексировалась, но в поиске так и нечего не появилось.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

**[Структурированная разметка вашей главной веб-страницы](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Ffashion-flash.de%2F)** имеет основное свойство как **[ShoppingCenter](http://schema.org/ShoppingCenter)**. Обратите внимание, что это свойство применяется для разметки физических торговых центров, а ваш веб-сайт является е-коммерческим (если я правильно понял). Если же ваш веб-сайт принадлежит к физическому торговому центру, то надо обозначить явно это в содержании веб-сайта, возможно в описании. Также надо явно указать максимально возможные данные на веб-странице Контакты. В документации Гугл о **[Google Knowledge Graph Search API](https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/)**, в главе "Объекты Graph", указаны типы объектов, которые поддерживаются Google Knowledge Graph. в этом списке нет объекта е-коммерции. Также обратите внимание, что указанная выше структурированная разметка вашей веб-страницы имеет 40 предупреждений. Это также понижает способность поисковиков правильно понимать ваш веб-сайт.

Кроме того, ваш веб-сайт имеет очень низкую скорость загрузки = **[19/100 для моб. и 22/100 для настольных компьютеров](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffashion-flash.de%2F&tab=mobile)**. В **[Официальном блоге Вебмастер Гугл](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/01/what-crawl-budget-means-for-googlebot.html)**, глава "Предел скорости сканирования", сообщается:

> "если сайт реагирует очень быстро на какое-то время, предел увеличивается, что означает, что для обхода можно использовать больше подключений. Если сайт замедляется или реагирует на ошибки сервера, предел снижается, а робот Googlebot обходится меньше."

Также **[Гугл сообщает](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html)**:

> "мы включаем новый сигнал в наших поисковых алгоритмов ранжирования: скорость сайта."

Возможно Гугл просто мало внимания уделяет вашему веб-сайту, по причине его низкой оптимизации. Инвестируйте ваше время в поисковую оптимизацию.